# How to make a line in illustrator with $ signs

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, symbols, stroke, path

The behavior I'm looking for is similar to how one can make a path line dashed. Except, instead of being dashes, I'd love to make it show $ signs. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Method one - works with any shape.

Create a no-fill, no-stroke rectangle and place a $ sign in the middle of it. $ sign **must be on top** of the rectangle. The amount of space between the $ sign and the rectangle edges will determine the spacing between the repeated $ signs.

Drag all that to the Brush panel and choose Pattern Brush when asked. Then click OK twice (you shouldn't need to adjust any brush options).

**Note:** the $ **must be art, not type** so if you set it as type use Type > Create Outlines before dragging things to the Brush Panel.

Then simply draw a path and click the pattern brush you just created in the Brush Panel.

[image: $ brush]

### Method Two - Text on a Path - better for text objects

Draw a path and use the Type on a Path tool to convert the path to a text baseline and then just type $ signs and spaces (or adjust tracking).

[image: type on path]

[image: text path]

This method allows you to treat the $ signs as text still so you can alter the font, spacing, size, etc., as often as you need.